# Jackson objectmapper ignores additional '}' at the end of json string while deserialising json string to object

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have following code.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Mahesh\", \"age\":21}}";

        try{
            Student student = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Student.class);

            System.out.println(student);

            jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(student);

            System.out.println(jsonString);
        }
        catch (JsonParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (JsonMappingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Student(){}
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Student [ name: "+name+", age: "+ age+ " ]";
    }
}
```

As we can see, string which I am passing to `mapper.readValue` is invalid json string(has additional `}` at the end). But when I run the code it runs successfully and giving following output.

```
Student [ name: Mahesh, age: 21 ]
{
  "name" : "Mahesh",
  "age" : 21
}
```

I was `JsonParseException` but it's not throwing an exception?

Does anyone know why ObjectMapper ignore additional `}` at the end of json String while deserialising?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when the parser can detect the end of the JSON string, it will ignore whatever comes after. Some parser gives this auto-fix facility.

An issue was raised with the same problem in 
[jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/726)  and there reply was

> Yes. This is by design. If you want to catch such problems, you need
>   to construct JsonParser, advance it manually. Existence of multiple
>   root-level values is not considered a validity problem, but in your
>   case, end-of-stream without matching ']'  would be caught.

Comment: Did you get your answer? Inform me if you have any query